# Cosa significa "di volta in volta" ?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Sono piuttosto confusa sul significato di "di volta in volta". Per intuizione io direi che vuol dire **solo qualche volta**, però leggendo su internet trovo che in realtà lo si intende come **ogni volta**.

Che cosa significa?

Comment: @Josh61, non c'è bisogno di cancellare la risposta; andava bene, basta modificarla un po'.

Answer (score 5):

Alla voce “[volta](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/volta1/)” del dizionario Treccani è riportata esplicitamente l'espressione “di volta in volta”, parafrasata con “a volta a volta, a turno, secondo un dato avvicendamento”.

Quindi, sì, significa “ogni volta” con in più un esplicito riferimento a “turni” o occasioni distinte.

Modificando lievemente un buon esempio di @Josh61, potremmo scrivere «I requisiti per essere candidabili alle elezioni saranno determinati dagli Stati membri di volta in volta», indicando che a ogni tornata elettorale verrà emanata una norma specifica.

Answer (score 1):

Che viene preso in considerazione quando è necessario.

> Comprare le cose quando servono, di volta in volta

Answer (score 0):

Forse ti aiuta anche una canzone di Ivano Fossati ("I treni a vapore")
dove al ritornello dice

Come i treni a vapore 
come i treni a vapore 
di stazione in stazione 
e di porta in porta 
e di pioggia in pioggia 
e di dolore in dolore 
il dolore passerà.

Di ... e di ... danno a me un senso di continuità ma precisa e ripetuta. Quindi dipende dal contesto. Di quante "volte" si tratta?